# Unable to retrieve NSArray from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSMutableArray` and 2 `NSDictionaries`. I want to save them on button press in one VC to another class. The problem is, when I retrieve those arrays later, when I already have made changes to them, I get *not the arrays I was saving*, but the actual arrays for the moment of retrieving.

What could be the reason for it? I tried creating new arrays and dictionaries with this method, but it didn't help:

```
- (void)recordValues {

    NSMutableArray *betaArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:labelsArray];
    newMailVC.bakcupLabelsArray = betaArray;
    NSLog(@"LABELS ARRAY COUNT ON SAVE IS %i", labelsArray.count);
    NSMutableDictionary *alphaDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:labelsDictionary];
    newMailVC.backupLabelsDictionary = alphaDictionary;
    NSMutableDictionary *betaDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:senderEmailsDictionary];
    newMailVC.backupEmailsDictionary = betaDictionary;
}
```

P.S. I can't use `NSUserDefaults` because `NSArrays` contain `UIViews` and I want to transfer the arrays to another view, in the state they were when I pressed the button and saved them with the method above, not with the state the view unloads. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I retrieve values like this on `ViewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)retrieveValues {

    labelsArray = newMailVC.bakcupLabelsArray;
    labelsDictionary = newMailVC.backupLabelsDictionary;
    senderEmailsDictionary = newMailVC.backupEmailsDictionary;

    NSLog(@"LABELS ARRAY COUNT ON RETRIEVE IS %i", labelsArray.count);
}
```

And when I do this for the first time everything is OK, but when I do this for the second time `NSLog` gives me 0 objects in my array.

Comment: implement property methods like setbackupLabelsDictionary and retain or assign it your dictionary.

Comment: @fibnochi so you suggest a separate method for each object? And how would they look like?

Comment: Your `bakcupLabelsArray` `backupLabelsDictionary` `backupEmailsDictionary` should be properties with retain. I think these objects are get autoreleased when you go to the next VC

Comment: @Anil nah, still doesn't work, no matter what I try

Comment: Your question confusing me.. can explain it or share some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely newMailVC.bakcupLabelsArray and the other 2 are not properties that are set to retain or copy their value. arrayWithArray: and dictionaryWithDictionary: create autoreleased versions of those objects, so they're probably getting released, which is why your count is 0 on subsequent checks.

So you can also fix by using `[[alloc] initWithArray:]` instead of `arrayWithArray:`, so that the objects don't go away. Just don't forget to release before setting the 2nd time.

Also, if they're mutable arrays and dictionaries, and you're going to be doing this operation multiple times, why are you re-init'ing every time? Why not just init those objects in the constructor, and then remove all objects and add new objects from array when you're doing the save operation. I.e., replace the contents of the array/dictionary instead of reinitializing it, that's what the mutable versions allow you to do.

"bakcup" is also misspelled, just FYI.

Comment: I'm using ARC, so no release is needed, yeah and I know about the backup thing, thanks ;)